# Only remove numbers inside parentheses (brackets)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Using the code below, I can turn `Number123(45)` into `Number`.

```
$string = 'Number123(45)';
$string2 = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $string);
echo $string2;
```

How would I only remove the numbers inside parentheses (brackets) so that the output is `Number123()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Include the parentheses in the pattern, like so:

```
$string = 'Number123(45)';
$string2 = preg_replace('/\([0-9]+\)/', '()', $string);
echo $string2;
```

Output:

> Number123()